# Problem with Replace Function

Tags: sql, replace, db2

In one of my resultsets i have column with char - data. I want to create another column, which carries altered data from the first column. There i want to exchange all 'ö' with oe.

I tried it like this:

```
Select NAME1,
    case when POSSTR(NAME1, 'ö') is not null then REPLACE(NAME1, 'ö', 'oe')
    end As __NAME1
from xyz;
```

and it failed. I don't get an error, but the ö is not replaced.

Am i making a mistake or is it simply not possible to perform this operation?

Thanks!
Patrick

Comment: Your actual question doesn't seem to match with your question title since the problem is in one of the functions not working correctly and not the fact that you are creating names for them. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you try adding WHERE POSSTR(NAME1, 'ö') IS NOT NULL to the query? That will at least tell you which function isn't working as expected.

Comment: You are quite right about the title. I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the DB2 documentation, POSSTR returns 0 (not NULL) if the string is not found.

Comment: It works when state the query like this: Select cu.NAME1, case WHEN (POSSTR(lower(cu.NAME1), 'ö') <> 0) THEN '-------' ELSE '-' end As CusName1,       With the query below i get no error but the ö isn't changed also. I guess something is wrong with my usage of the replace function? WHEN (POSSTR(lower(cu.NAME1), 'ö') <> 0) THEN REPLACE(lower(cu.NAME1), 'ö', 'oe')

Answer (score 1):

You you want your second column to list all the rows, both changed and unchanged you can simply use:

```
Select 
    NAME1,
    REPLACE(NAME1, 'ö', 'oe') As __NAME1
from xyz;
```

also you can test this:

```
Select 
    NAME1,
    REPLACE(NAME1, 'ö', 'oe') As __NAME1
from 
    xyz
where
    POSSTR(NAME1, 'ö') <> 0
```